# read.csv ;check.names=F; R;Look at the picture,why it works a treat?

Tags: r, read.csv

[please see the the column name "if" in the second column,the deifference is :when `check.name=F`,"." beside "if" disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaG2G.png)

[image]

Sorry for the code,because I try to type some codes to generate this data.frame like in the picture,but i failed due to the "if".We know that "if" is a reserved word in R(like else,for, while ,function).And here, i deliberately use the "if" as the column name (the 2nd column),and see whether R will generate some novel things.
So using another way, I type the "if" in the excel and save as the format of csv in order to use `read.csv`.

Question is:
Why "if." changes to "if"?(After i use check.names=FALSE)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVu0d.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: "Column names are often data, and the underlying make.names() transformation is non-invertible, so the default behaviour corrupts data. To avoid this, set check.names = FALSE." ———quoted from [link](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/names-and-values.html)  ,this trigers my curiosity so i try some code above. Because I am afraid of the meeting the same problem when using some big data with millions of columns.And in that case,i will hardly find where goes wrong.             Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?read.csv` describes `check.names=` in a similar fashion:

```
check.names: logical.  If 'TRUE' then the names of the variables in the
          data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically
          valid variable names.  If necessary they are adjusted (by
          'make.names') so that they are, and also to ensure that there
          are no duplicates.
```

The default action is to allow you to do something like `dat$<column-name>`, but unfortunately `dat$if` will fail with `Error: unexpected 'if' in "dat$if"`, ergo `check.names=TRUE` changing it to something that the parser will not trip over. Note, though, that `dat[["if"]]` will work even when `dat$if` will not.

If you are wondering if `check.names=FALSE` is ever a *bad* thing, then imagine this:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text = "a,a\n2,3")
dat
#   a a.1
# 1 2   3

dat <- read.csv(text = "a,a\n2,3", check.names = FALSE)
dat
#   a a
# 1 2 3
```

In the second case, how does one access the second column *by-name*? `dat$a` returns `2` only. However, if you don't want to use `$` or `[[`, and instead can rely on positional indexing for columns, then `dat[,colnames(dat) == "a"]` does return both of them.